# How can I fix a JAVAC Invalid flag error?

Tags: bash, shell, javac

I'm trying to compile a shell script with `javac` and it keeps returning me this error:

```
$ bash run_RGE.sh

javac: invalid flag: Element.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
javac: invalid flag: RGE.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
javac: invalid flag: -Xms1024m
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
sleep: missing operand
Try "sleep --help" for more information.
```

My shell script looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
export LIB=C:/home/b04280/Transfert/Libs/
CLASSPATH=$(echo "$LIB"/*.jar | tr ' ' ':')
export ficIn=C:/home/b04280/Transfert/rgeII.xlsx/
export repIn=C:/home/b04280/Transfert/rgeII/
export repOut=C:/home/b04280/Transfert/rgeIIcible/
javac -cp $CLASSPATH Element.java
javac -cp $CLASSPATH RGE.java
javac -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -cp $CLASSPATH  RGE $ficIn $repIn $repOut > docx.txt
sleep
```

I am wondering where this error comes from, I looked at other questions on here regarding the same topic but their solutions didn't seem fit to my particular case.

Any help please? Thanks in advance.

PS. I also have the sleep error (I "translated" this script from batch --> shell and "sleep" was the replacement I found for "pause")

Comment: Use `bash -x run_RGE.sh`, it will show the expanded commands it's running.

Comment: What are you running your bash script on by the way? If it's `git bash` or  `cygwin` that might work, but on a real Unix OS the `echo "$LIB"/*.jar` part won't work with a windows path

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; I'm running it on an Linux Virtual Machine. Specifically Mobaxterm.

Comment: in a terminal, what happens when you do `cd C:/home/b04280/Transfert/Libs/` ? As Aaron mentioned, I suspect your script is not working because you are mentioning the `C:` drive in your path (which does not exist on linux)

Comment: not familiar with the tool, but a quick glance at its doc makes me think it doesn't translate windows paths to unix paths like Cygwin and git bash do. That would mean "C:/home/b04280/Transfert/Libs/" isn't a directory from the point of view of your script

Comment: Also, each entry in the CLASSPATH contains a colon, but the CLASSPATH is colon-separated.

Comment: colon-separated on unix, semi-colon separated on windows. If mobaXTerm's environment is a real virtual machine whithout access to the OS that runs it then OP is executing a linux binary version of java, on the other hand if it's an unix-like overlay like Cygwin and Git Bash it's likely running the windows binary version of java

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. I removed the C: and now I'm just focused on sucessfully adding the multiple jars in Libs to my classpath. I tried CLASSPATH=$(echo "$LIB"/*.jar) and I'm still getting errors, however. Any recommendations on alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should be closer to what you need :

```
#!/bin/bash
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
lib=/home/b04280/Transfert/Libs
classpath=$(echo "$lib"/*.jar | tr ' ' ':')
fic_in=/home/b04280/Transfert/rgeII.xlsx/
rep_in=/home/b04280/Transfert/rgeII/
rep_out=/home/b04280/Transfert/rgeIIcible/
javac -cp "$classpath" Element.java
javac -cp "$classpath" RGE.java
java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -cp "$classpath" RGE "$fic_in" "$rep_in" "$rep_out" > docx.txt
```

In particular :

- unix paths
- quoted variables to avoid them being parsed as multiple arguments if their values contain spaces
- in the last command RGE is a class name rather than a file path, you specify memory settings, plus the command produces useful output ; it seems to me it should execute the code (`java`) rather than compile it (`javac`)
- I'm not sure it's necessary, but removing the trailing slash from `$LIB`'s value avoids having double slashes in `$CLASSPATH` which might confuse `java[c]`
- removed the useless `export`s (they'd be useful if you invoked other bash scripts or binaries that would rely on those variables being set, but you're just passing them as parameters)
- applied naming conventions (avoid uppercase variables as they might conflict with environment variables, use `snake_case` rather than `camelCase`).

I'm not sure in your context whether you're executing the linux version of the `java[c]` binaries or the windows one. If it's the windows one you'll need to replace the `tr ' ' ':'` part by `tr ' ' ';'` as the classpath on windows is semi-colon separated rather than colon-separated.